# I see same links for downloading Play 2.4.x and Play 2.3.x

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to learn Play Framework to start using this in my existing project which is targeted for Java 7 alone. So, I try to download old version 2.3.9 which supports Java 6+. But in site I see same activator url to download old versions as well. How could activator know that I am planning to use Play 2.3.9 version. I am getting `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` when I try to run sample application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play version is set in the [`plugins.sbt` file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Build):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % playVersion)
```

If you want to use Play 2.3.9, you should use:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.9")
```